# Communicating between ZMQ sockets in a distributed system over the internet

Tags: sockets, client-server, zeromq

I've been working on a distributed system project, my system is partially p2p. My issue is super simple, I don't know how people usually solve it, because I have no experience in this domain, I am very new to this all.

**I want to communicate over the internet between two clients, which both have ZMQ sockets**.

On my local network, or my machine, they seem to work fine, but when communicating over the internet, I never get my message. I have shortlisted this to 2 reasons :

**1 )** The NAT - it is not letting my message reach the client host, does anyone know how to solve the issue of NAT within ZMQ, I have heard of TCP hole punching and such, how do web developers and other people who deal with this thing often manage this ?

**2 )** ZMQ sockets can not communicate over the internet, even if the communication is strictly between the two ZMQ sockets and not BSD sockets etc. I am not sure about this one though.

If anyone has expertise in this area I would be grateful and it would help me move forward thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *<sub>2 ) ZMQ sockets can not communicate over the internet, even if the communication is strictly between the two ZMQ sockets</sub>*

### Well, 2 ) is easy, ZeroMQ sockets obviously work over the Internet .

There is not much to add to this.

> *<sub>1 ) The NAT - it is not letting my message reach the client host,</sub>*

### The 1 ) will deserve a bit more attention :

Right, NAT could be in place, when local LAN(s) routers are connected to a single public ( registered, coordinated IPv4 / IPv6 address ).

Next, there could be another show-stopper in the game, the FireWall, put in one or more places (!) -- be it a local one ( O/S operated, which one can check, if having administrator-grade login to the localhost ), or a one, integrated into any of  the Gateway/Proxy/Policy enforcement.

In any case, thorough design-review ought take place with your local administrator(s), responsible for the localhost-O/S and network-infrastructure elements and a network-wide responsible security-manager / engineer(s).

### The "*HOW ?*" part :

This ( principal ) complexity is exactly why Game Studios try to avoid user's headaches on solving these complexities and try to provide some escape strategy.

**For a trivial case 1-to-1 :**
One may indeed use a set of rules for a port-forwarding setup ( if FireWall + Gateway engineering permits ) and your ZeroMQ connectivity may get directed  onto a
**`tcp://<public-IP>:<_a_port#_known_to_be_FWDed_to_a_target_HOST_>`** address.

**For more, but still units :**
This scenario may seem easy for a single connection setup, yet if in a need to have units or tens of target hosts, there would be a rather limited will from the gateway ( router ) / firewall admins to open more and more ports on the wild side of the security perimeter. Here another trick may help - using a standard **`ssh`**-tools, where connections could harness so called local-port-forwarding and remote-port-forwarding, and the interconnects enjoy a single-port to pass firewall + gateway, plus the content is encryption-protected. Sure, more administrative efforts are needed on both sides, yet, a known and smart way to go, if these efforts and a bit increased latency ( encryption + decryption processing added ) do not spoil your in-game UX latency plans.

**For more, above a few units :**
There is an option of re-using an ad-hoc, yet a security threating dual-sided sword - a multi-player shared (!) VPN, which solves the global "visibility" issues ( most often with some central ( be it published or not ) service-provisioning mapping and authentication serving coordinator ). The localhost side applications simply start to see another "local"-interface, uncoordinated with respect to its IPv4 / IPv6 address(es), yet this private-shared-VPN seems to be joining all the players so as to look as if all of these share one common IP-network, having effectively bypassed all the security/firewalling efforts of the common network practices --- which is at the same time its strongest risk for putting in place ( not mentioning the risk of the principal SPOF in the remote, central, authorisation/mapping service-provider, be theirs set of motivations published or hidden ).

Gaming industry panicked on all these issues since Multi-Player games started to be sold ( which for 2018/Q2 Gamers may look as **since ever** ) and the industry was trying to avoid exactly all these complexity-related pains, as a dominant fraction of game-buying teenagers was not expected to also have acquired both the patient persistence ( to systematically craft the proper setup ) and the deep-enough knowledge ( so as to know all the system-wide details of where and what to setup or re-configure, so as to unlock a secure end-to-end online in-game visibility ).

**For indeed many-to-many cases :**
A nice example was started in late 1990-ies / early 2000-ies when IL-2 Sturmovik's Community of Pilots and Virtual Squadrons went operational 24/7/365 "since ever". They used a Community sponsored **HyperLobby** a **Mediating Node** to have all these complexities solved once and forever for all interested Members. HyperLobby lightweight client/server service-infrastructure was doing all the port-forwarding mapping setups and other server-side mediations dirty hacks all invisible to Pilot(s) and provided added means for administering indeed many connected Multi-Player Game Theatres for IL-2, F/A-18, Su-27 Flanker, CFS, Medal Of Honor and many more, than I try to remember today ( topping above small tens of thousands of connected Pilots IIRC in peak hours ). A great piece of sound design and distinguished efforts for decades for the truly Global online Community ( having an honor to serve in pseudohistorical VFSQ, with members spanning 13 TimeZones - from Hawaii, Brasil, U.S., U.K., France, Germany, Italy, Greece to Turkey - flying with similarly minded friends from Japan, Australia, New Zealand and many other places, round the globe -- be it East/West Front + Pacific Theater globally coordinated weekend-events - missions reconstructed till the very historical details or enjoyed the Memorial Parade Flyovers on V-Day-s' anniversaries ) -- **~Salute~** Jiri Fojtasek, well done indeed! -- idea of which helps to illustrate the way to go / follow ( as many younger game-portals indeed did follow this path ).